# How to convert the date format "/Date(253402214400000+0000)/" into yyyyMMdd:hhmmss in Java?

Tags: java, date, datetime-format, epoch, datetime-conversion

Today we have the date/time in epoch format `"/Date(16747622680000)/"` which can be easy converted into yyyyMMdd:hhmmss when getting the digits as milliseconds from the String and pass it to an instance of `java.util.Date today = new Date(16747622680000);` and then use a `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` instance to get the expected result.

But what does the `"+0000"` in `"/Date(253402214400000+0000)/"` mean and how to convert that value?

Comment: Just a bit of a guess, but it seems like it would be a time zone offset value (maybe `ZZZZ`)

Comment: *"and then use a `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` instance to get the expected result"* and, no, don't do that.  Instead make use of the newer and improved `java.time` APIs

Comment: `new Date(16747622680000)` and again, no, don't do that.  Use `LocalDateTime.now()` or `ZonedDateTime.now()` instead

Comment: Did you really mean 14 digits in your example input of `16747622680000`? Or is that an typo, one too many zero digits on the end?

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

The `+0000` means an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

(Deleted last digit zero (`0`) of example input, presumed to be a typo)

```
Instant
.ofEpochMilli( 
    "/Date(1674762268000)/".replace( "/" , "" ).replace( "Date(" , "" ).replace( ")" , "" ).replace( "/" , "" )
)
.toString()
```

See this [code run at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Nh6MkJ).

> 2023-01-26T19:44:28Z

The `Z` on the end and the `+0000` seen in your Question, both mean an [**offset from UTC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

## *java.time*

> an instance of java.util.Date today = new Date(16747622680000); and then use a java.text.SimpleDateFormat

No, never use `Date` & `SimpleDateFormat`. These classes are now legacy and are terribly flawed, designed by people who did not understand date-time handling. They were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

> we have the date/time in epoch format "/Date(16747622680000)/"

First, clean your input string to get only digits.

Also, I assume you made a typo, with an extra zero digit at the end. I removed that digit.

```java
String input = "/Date(1674762268000)/";
String inputDigits = input.replace( "/" , "" ).replace( "Date(" , "" ).replace( ")" , "" ).replace( "/" , "" );
long countFromEpoch1970Utc = Long.parseLong( inputDigits );
```

At this point, we have a `long` integer number with the value 1_674_762_268_000L.

> countFromEpoch1970Utc = 1674762268000

Parse that number as a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of the first moment of 1970 as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

```java
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( countFromEpoch1970Utc );
```

See this [code run at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Nh6MkJ).

> instant.toString(): 2023-01-26T19:44:28Z

## ISO 8601

The text in the string `2023-01-26T19:44:28Z` is in a format defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about the virtues of using only ISO 8601 formats when communicating date-time data textually.

The `Z` on the end is pronounced “Zulu”, and means an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. Another standard way to write an offset of zero is `+00:00`. The ISO 8601 standard permits omitting the COLON character, to get `+0000` as seen in your Question.

I recommend always including the COLON character in an offset, as well as always including the leading padding zero when needed. While both are optional in the standard, I have seen multiple libraries and protocols that expect them.

Comment: The count of milliseconds until 9999-12-31T00:00:00Z are 253402214400000. So we don't talk about a typo.